# Let $p$ a prime number, then prove that : $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{p} \binom {p}{k} \binom{p+k}{k} \equiv 2^p +1 \pmod{p^2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

First we know the fact that $p$ divides $\binom {p}{k}$ for $k\in \{1,\ldots,p-1\}$.

Second we have : $\binom {p+k}{k}= \frac{(p+k)\cdots(p+1)}{k!}$ which means : $k!\binom {p+k}{k}=(p+k)\cdots(p+1)$.

Notice that every term of the product is divided by $p$ except the last product $k(k-1)\cdots1=k!$

So $p$ divides $k!(\binom {p+k}{k} - 1)$. By Gauss lemma for $k\in \{1,\ldots,p-1\}$, $p$ divides $(\binom {p+k}{k} - 1)$.

Then $p^2$ divides $\binom{p}{k}(\binom {p+k}{k} - 1)$. We obtain : $\binom{p}{k}(\binom {p+k}{k} \equiv \binom{p}{k} \pmod{p^2}$.

So : $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{p} \binom {p}{k} \binom{p+k}{k}\equiv 1 +\binom{2p}{p} + \sum \limits_{k=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{k} \equiv 1 +\binom{2p}{p} +2^{p}-2 \pmod{p^2}$

Then I'm stuck...

Maybe it is possible to prove that $\binom{2p}{p} \equiv 2\pmod{p^2}$..

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Would rewriting $\displaystyle{p+k\choose k}~=~\displaystyle(-1)^k~{-p-1\choose k}$ help in any way ?

Comment: See Wolstenholme's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\binom{2p}{p}\equiv 2\mod{p^2}$. This is clearly true for $p=3$, and for $p>3$, this [mathworld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralBinomialCoefficient.html) gives a reference to show that in fact $\binom{2p}{p}\equiv 2\mod{p^3}$.

Comment: It is easy with Wolstenholme's theorem, but without this result is there another method more elementary ?

Comment: @Maman I'm not sure there is. I tried proving it directly, and ended up having to find $\sum 1\cdot 2\cdots \hat{i}\cdots (p-3)$, which is reminiscent of Wolstenholme's theorem.

Comment: Apparently the easiest way is to use a polynom in $X=p$ for $\binom{2p}{p}-2$ but I do not find that it is elementary...